# Switch python version in Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I'm using Python 3.6 installed with pyenv and apt-get. In the shell if I do `python3 --version` it shows

```
python3 --version
Python 3.6.0
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 ARM version, and it comes with Python 3.8 installed. However, when running a test command, it's invoking `/usr/bin/python3` which is `Python 3.8`. I'm getting the following error:

```
import pexpect
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py:75: in <module>
    from .pty_spawn import spawn, spawnu
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py:14: in <module>
    from .spawnbase import SpawnBase
E     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 224
E       def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False):
E                                                                  ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Under the hood, it's still using `Python 3.8`. How can I fix that?

** Update ** Since `Python 3.7` `async` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: `make check` from where? Python's own `Makefile`? Since 3.7 (IIRC) `async` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: ... But not actually answered the crucial question. Which `Makefile` and how exactly does it run `python`?

Comment: Maybe try running your test command from within active virtual environment? Also try setting `pyenv global 3.6.0` to use shim provided by pyenv.